# How to import BR class while implementing two way data binding? Importing BR shows error in my code

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am inheriting BaseObservable class. In 'notifyPropertyChanged' method when i am passing integer fieldId, 'BR' class shows red error.
I am trying to implement two-way data binding.

**ViewModel.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class ViewModel extends BaseObservable {
String username;
String password;

@Bindable
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.username);
}
@Bindable
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The problem is in the latest version of IDE i.e. Android Studio 3.3 . It's working fine in version 3.2.1 . I hope that Google resolves this issue soon.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's issue with Android Studio (I'm using data binding in AS 3.3).
Problem is, that when you use `BR`, it will show you it doesn't exist before it's generated (meaning, you need to create layout first and build it and then you'll be able to import it).

Try adding `import com.example.test.BR;` to the file (change with your package if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR in your java domain class.

In some cases, even if you don't import it, no matter it shows errors, the code will compile. But after import, the errors will go away.

Android Studio 3.5.3